# BigQuery ETL and Calculations

Tags: types, etl, numeric

Please assist? I am pulling in data from Campaign manager as a Google Sheet and than import into Google Bigquery. Problems arise like, wrong data types and numeric values that are not correct(round up or round down). What would be the best way to avoid all of these problems?

Is it better to do a direct ETL from my data source with an ETL tool. Leave the figures as it is and do my calculations to my reports in Tableau/Powerbi?

Answer (score -1):

Did you find a solution to this?

Yes, it's better to use an ETL.I am currently using the Stitch ETL platform to extract data from Campaign Manager (CM) and send it to BigQuery. I am then visualising my data in PowerBi. This works extremely well and I have encountered no issues such as the ones you describe. I have not tried to export CM data to sheets but have a lot of experience with using sheets in similar situations. While they have some short term utility I would always recommend using an ETL to have greater control and fewer limitations. Larger data sets will ultimately be more than Google Sheets can manage, for example.